# RecycleView Interface Crashing

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am doing my project which i need to fetch data from FIREBASE when the reference/child's value changes in RecycleView and CardView. There's no error in my coding but when i attempt to enter that interface, it crash. I will attach my coding below, if everyone know what's the problem pls tell me.Thanks a lot.

MainAlarm.java

```
package com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;



import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainAlarm extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_alarm);
       recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        new GetDataFromFirebase().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        // Read from the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Resort");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot alert: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println(alert.getValue());
                }
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(values));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                System.out.println("Failed to read value." + error.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    private class GetDataFromFirebase extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }
}
```

MainAlarm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainAlarm"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:background="@drawable/blue1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
    >


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

RecycleViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> values;
    RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.RecycleViewAdapter,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(values.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
        }
    }
}
```

RecycleViewAdapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_item"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="8dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
        android:minLines="4"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Logcat

```
11-08 21:17:22.248 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
11-08 21:17:22.252 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-08 21:17:22.261 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-08 21:17:22.276 15287-15305/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-08 21:17:22.390 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
11-08 21:17:22.394 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
11-08 21:17:22.557 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/Utils: Utils_isSuperResolutionSupport [load libai_client.so failed]
11-08 21:17:22.921 15287-15311/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 E/vndksupport: Could not load vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so" not found.
11-08 21:17:23.033 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
11-08 21:17:23.044 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/InputMethodManager: startInputOrWindowGainedFocus failed. Window focus may have already been lost. win=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2c5dbf8 view=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{1ec1b0c VFED..CL. .F....ID 110,554-610,645 #7f08004a app:id/email},focus=true,windowFocus=true,window=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2c5dbf8,temporaryDetach=false
11-08 21:17:23.139 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
11-08 21:17:24.529 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
11-08 21:17:24.575 15287-15287/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 5
```

Comment: You should post your stacktrace to see where the error is.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Please post the error message from logcat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @Gonzalo sorry that i dont know how to check for stacktrace..i m newbie to this

Comment: @AlexMamo my logcat is too long. exceed characters limit

Comment: Add just the important part.

Comment: add only the stacktrace, no need to add whole logcat

Comment: @AlexMamo done, can you pls check?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko updated logcat

Comment: @JesscyTey that's wrong part of the logcat. Please post the exception stacktrace

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko would you mind to teach me how to do that ? i google but dont understand

Comment: @JesscyTey Open ur Logcat, and in the top right corner of your Logcat, you'll find a drop down. In that choose, **Show only selected applications** . Also set the Log level(another drop down) to **Error** . Now while your Logcat is open, recreate the crash in your app, the first thing that appears in the Logcat should be your error stacktrace. It might start with something like ( *java.lang.RuntimeException* or *Fatal Exception*).

Comment: Unfortunately, it would take too long. Make sure you have checked the question I linked as possible duplicate

Comment: @VishistVarugeese this app doesnt force stop or what, when i try to get into the recyclerview, it will quit that interface and back to Main Interface

Comment: @JesscyTey You've mentioned in your question that the app crashes. If it actually does crash then to get the error, follow the instructions I've posted earlier.